# prevent script execution on load (or parsing) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an "ajax engine" based on jQuery. And after receiving the response i must manipulate the response before inserting in page. But I need the response as an jQuery object.
I do this with:

```
tmpActualResult = $( '<span/>' ).html( actualResult );
```

But at this time jQuery (or browser itself?) execute the scripts which are included in response - and exactly this shouldn't occur. I will execute the scripts manual later.

in particular I will:

1. parse response (get access to the tags/elements which are included)
2. insert the elements into page (DOM manipulating)
3. execute possible scripts (which are received)

in thanks

Edit:
If someone is interested too, i've created a more general solution by extending the jQuery.domManip function, as suggested in first answer.

```
(function($, oldDomManip) {
// Override the core domManip function
$.fn.domManip = function() {

    function evalScript(i, elem) {
        jQuery.globalEval(elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || "");
    }

    var scripts = [];
    // let jQuery build the fragments
    var results = jQuery.buildFragment(arguments[0], this, scripts);
    // change parameter to created fragments
    arguments[0] = results.fragment.childNodes;
    // do what jQuery will do - without scripts
    oldDomManip.apply(this, arguments);
    if (scripts.length) {
        // if connection is active
        if (jQuery.active != 0) {
            $(this).bind("ajaxStop.scriptCache", function() {
                $.each(scripts, evalScript);
                $(this).unbind("ajaxStop.scriptCache");
            });
        } else
            $.each(scripts, evalScript);
    }
    return this;
};
})(jQuery, jQuery.fn.domManip);
```

it will not execute scripts before ajax request is completed. worked for me.

Comment: What is exactly the response?

Comment: At this time a simple HTML String. (with possible script tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prevent script execution of scripts that are part of a string of markup you're trying to add using .html() or .append(). At least not without extending the domManip function of jQuery. It extracts all scripts in html markup that you're trying to add using .html() or .append() and evals it.

You could, however, extract the script tags with their inner text (js) from the string yourself, add only the markup via .html() or .append() and then eval the scripts yourself when you need to.

Comment: Ok thanks - and is there at least a possibility to get the scripts? 
like: $('<span/>').append(response).find("script");

Comment: You would have to get the scripts from the response before you put the response into the DOM (using the .append() function)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try to extend the domManip Function, i need a more global solution...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6BdWY/ this is some rough js to extract scripts from your response string. If my answer worked out for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: ah great - thanks

btw. sorry I'm new here :D
where can I mark it as solved or accepted? - i find no button or something like...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = "<div> i am html with script tag <script type="text/javascript">alert('Script executed');</script>end</div>"
$(container).doSomething()
```